# IIS proxy to SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, iis, proxy

I have a situation where in my web service is hosted on azure and SQL Server 2017 database is hosted on the companies internal and supports only LDAP authentication, to establish connectivity between my service and database. I would like to set up an IIS proxy with the app pool configured with the LDAP user that would forward requests to the SQL Server database.

Can you someone please help me out with that how I can achieve this or if there is an alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: IIS, a web server, as proxy of SQL Server, a database? What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a web api to access your company's database. Then host it in your company's DMZ server. So that your web app in azure would be able to access that API.

Of course, you could build a reverse proxy in DMZ for security reason.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing